# What is the most elegant way to choose what service implementation must be used?

Tags: java, spring, design-patterns, encapsulation

in my controller, I need to choose what service implementation I need to use on spring. Before I was encapsulating this code in a factory, but I think that its not a good practice...

```
@Component
public class StoreServiceFactory {

    @Autowired
    private List<StoreService> storeServices;

    public StoreService getService(){

        if(isActiveSale){
            return storeServices.get("PublicStoreService")
        }

        return storeServices.get("PrivateStoreService")
    }
}
```

So I would like to encapsulate this behaviour to not care about inside my controller.. How can I get it??

Comment: where is 'isActive' comming from?

Comment: @JensSchauder now is a method inside the factory...

Comment: Can value of 'isActiveSale' change on runtime? Is it a static property in some 'properties' file etc?

Comment: So where does it takes the information from? Is it some state of the application? Is it constant? does it change? when does it change?

Comment: looks like storeServices should be a Map<String, StoreService>, not a list

Comment: @JensSchauder this is an feature that we can set to on or off based on another service... If the sales campaign is not active, we use one service if its active, then we use another service..it can change when app is running..

Comment: @JensSchauder we turn one different business logic if we have sales... in specifics dates we turn this on... after we turn off and the app behavior changes...

Comment: Then what I wrote in the answer holds: I don't see a reason to change this.

Comment: @JensSchauder It's ok to factory decide what implementation should return? or the getService() method should get an serviceName parameter and match based on this value? And this flow control (isActiveSale) will be on controller.

Answer (score 0):

If `isActiveSale` changes when the application is running, I think that what you got is a good solution. Since the Controller is a singleton you can't expect a different injection everytime this value changes.
If you get the value only on the startup of the application(e.g. from some property) you can use a profile.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with a factory, although as @R4J points out in the comments it is more of a provider, since it doesn't instantiate anything. I would consider the factory/provider a good choice if the 'isActiveSale' status changes based on things outside of the current control flow, like a configuration in a property file. A setting set in some adminstration screen, or maybe based on the time of day.

Comment: But since it does not create any instances of 'StoreService' thus it is not a factory ;) I'd call it StoreServiceResolver/Provider?